# java batch select or multiple selects in parallel

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, jdbc

I have this package function call where I provide all the parameters to, through java:

```
select package.function(?,?,?) from dual;
```

One of the parameters takes in a list of ids. There is a lot of processing/comparing that occurs in this function, so there has been performance issues (getting the results takes too long) that occur when the size of the list grows beyond 500.

So the solution that I have been trying to accomplish was to run multiple `select` calls (with a split list of ids) in parallel through Oracle JDBC or Spring JDBC template. Unfortunately, I am using Oracle JDBC which does not support batch `SELECT` operations, and I also could not find any online resources about batch `selects` for `jdbctemplate`.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve parallel execution in the DAO layer, or run multiple `select` calls at the same time, or batch `SELECT`?

Comment: You need to identify where the time is being spent. It might be better to show us what you are trying to do, so that an appropriate solution can be presented.

Comment: JDBC only supports batch updates, so a JDBC driver will not have such a thing, nor will things built on JDBC. You will need to program it yourself (eg by splitting it across multiple connections and multiple threads); although I would guess it won't give you the performance benefit you think it will give.